# Delete all occurrences of an item and the one following it in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a single column pandas dataframe with column name `0`. Following is the code i wrote to delete all occurrences of the string `' & \n'`:

```
df.drop(df[(df[0] == ' & \n')].index, inplace=True)
```

and this worked successfully.

What I wish to do is also remove the row that immediately follows the rows that I dropped in above code.

One way I thought of is getting the indices of all the removals that I need to make.

```
listofremovals = df.index[df[0] == ' & \n'].tolist()

for i in range(len(listofremovals)):
    listofremovals.append(listofremovals[i]+1)
listofremovals.sort()
```

and then `df.drop(listofremovals, inplace=True)`

This works fine, but there should be a simpler method that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) for next rows, chain by original with `|` for bitwise OR and last remove rows by invert mask by `~` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         0:['new',' & \n','a',' & \n', 'w','ee']
})

print (df)
       0
0    new
1   & \n
2      a
3   & \n
4      w
5     ee

m = (df[0] == ' & \n')
m1 = m.shift(fill_value=False)

df = df[~(m | m1)]
print (df)
     0
0  new
5   ee
```